# Storing nested loop values in a vector

Tags: r

I want to make the sum of squares of my data and save it to a vector. So I think I have to do a nested loop. First increasing the arbitrary number and second going through the different obseravtions. But it only works if I am using a matrix and summarize after via apply-function. However, I just wanna save my output directly in a vector w/o using a matrix and apply-function. Maybe I am just wrong and there is a much easier solution.

```
x <- 1:3 #data 
y <- 5:7 # arbitrary values

# doesnt work
ssq <- numeric()
for (j in 1:length(y)) {
  for (i in 1:length(x)){
    ssq[j] <-  (sum(((x[i]-y[j])^2)))
  }
}



# works
z <- matrix(nrow = length(x), ncol = length(y))

for (j in 1:length(y)) {
  for (i in 1:length(x)){
    z[i,j] <-  ((x[i]-y[j])^2)
  }
} 

ssq2 <- apply(z,2,sum)
```

Comment: If the question is how to get ssq2 shown at the end of the question but with less code then try `sapply(y, function(y) sum((x - y)^2))`  or 
`colSums(outer(x, y, "-")^2)`

Comment: @AnilGoyal, It runs without error but does not give the same value as ssq2 at the end of the question.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck, Revised the answer, actually I was trying to match output of `ssq2`

Comment: @G.Grothendieck well, thats easier than I thought. That's what I wanted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why double loops when R is already vectorised

```r
x <- 1:3 #data 
y <- 5:7 # arbitrary values

#loop
ssq <- numeric()

for(i in seq_along(y)){
  ssq[i] <- sum((x - y[i])^2)
}

ssq
#> [1] 29 50 77
#Map
unlist(Map(function(.y) sum((x - .y)^2), y))
#> [1] 29 50 77

#purrr::map_*
purrr::map_dbl(y,  ~sum((x - .x)^2))
#> [1] 29 50 77
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You might use a double loop if you wanted the sum of squares between every possible pair of values in `x` and `y`. Probably  you just want the ordered pairs (first in `x` with first in `y`, second in `x` with second in `y`, etc.). Since R has vectorization, you can do this very simply with no loops:

```
sum((x - y)^2)
# [1] 48
```

with no loops. If you wanted to be less efficient and use a loop, you would still only need a single loop:

```
ssq = 0
for(i in 1:length(x)) {
 ssq = ssq + (x[i] - y[i])^2
}
ssq
# [1] 48
```